# Not working servlet extracting value from database

Tags: java, ajax, database

I want to make a simple web application using `Ajax` on `Java`. I have a local database with one table - two columns: `ID` and `Surname`.

My application should display the user a correct `surname` (for example he wrote on site `id = 1` and  servlet should return surname from db.

This is my servlet:

```
package db.connection;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConnectionServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/ConnectionServlet")
public class ConnectionServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String key = req.getParameter("key");
        if (key != null) {

            String surname = "";

            ResultSet result = null;
            Connection con = null;
            try{
            con = DatabaseConnector.getConnection();
            Statement select = con.createStatement();
            result = select
                    .executeQuery("SELECT surname from person where ID = '"
                            + key + "';");

            //surname=result.getString(0);

            while (result.next()) {
                surname = result.getString("surname");
               // System.out.println(surname);

            }
            res.setContentType("text/xml");
            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            // write out the response string
            res.getWriter().write(surname);
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } }

            finally
                {
                    if (con != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            con.close();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    }
```

**`Ajax.js`**

```
 var req; 
  function getSurDB(){ 
    var key = document.getElementById("key"); 
    var keypressed = document.getElementById("keypressed"); 
    keypressed.value = key.value; 
    var url = "/DBcon/Ajax?key="+ escape(key.value); 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
      req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject){ 
      req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    } 
    req.open("Get",url,true); 
    req.onreadystatechange = callback; 
    req.send(null);
  } 

  function callback(){ 
    if (req.readyState==4){ 
      if (req.status == 200){ 
        var surname = document.getElementById('surname'); 
        surname.value = req.responseText; 
      } 
    }
    clear();
  } 
  function clear(){ 
    var key = document.getElementById("key"); 
    key.value=""; 
  }
  function focusIn(){ 
    document.getElementById("key").focus();
  }
```

Comment: Your intention is nice... but what problem have you faced?

Comment: Consider using prepared statements so you tackle SQL injection. Instead of executeQuery("SELECT surname from person where ID = '" + key + "';") More info: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java

Comment: User when wrote id on site not see anything.
Its my first homework. I know about SQL injection, but firstly i want see that this application work, and next i will think about safety.

Comment: @KrisPL when you use your browser to go to the servlet, for instance localhost:8080/YourProject/ConnectionServlet?key=yourkey do you get your expected result?

Comment: No, now i see tomcat error "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request."

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to find your problem because we don't know if your DatabaseConnector class is working or not. Also in the comments you say tomcat shows an error. You can check the tomcat console in your IDE or the tomcat log file and analyse the error (perhaps google it).

But I found an issue.
You set the content type of your response to "text/xml" but you return a String.
Try setting it to plain text:

```
res.setContentType("text/plain");
```

or return the surname as xml.